# define a external javascript function inside php

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to create a calculator using checkboxes, below is my code that works perfectly fine on html, but when this same code is in my php page I get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: priceCalc() is not defined at HTMLInputElement.oninput` when the `<script src="assets/scripts/myscript.js"></script>` is used in the php page it doesn't seem to work, only when I put the whole `priceCalc();` function inside my head tags, then it works, but I don't want to do that, I want the javascript to be on its own externally called myscript.js...

```js
function priceCalc() {

  var totalCost = 0;

  //If referral is checked apply discount
  if (document.getElementById("opt1").checked) {
    totalCost += 3000;
  }

  //prints the final price
  document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = "$" + totalCost.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<form method="post" oninput="priceCalc();">
  <div class="item-option">
    <label class="label">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="text" id="opt1"> Uranium $3000
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="price">
    <h3>Total estimated price: </h3>
    <p id="totalPrice">$0.00</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: without your php code it's impossible to guess what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, it's hard to say without your PHP code. But try the following:

1. Ensure your `<script>` tag(s) are in the `<head></head>` section
2. Double check your relative path in `<script src="assets/scripts/myscript.js"></script>`.

Testing in `plnkr.co` worked fine

Comment: welp, it turns out everything was fine and code was working, it was an issue with my Apache HTTP Server didn't update the save on myscript.js file.